# icon fonts - how to download the actual gliph

Tags: css, icons

I have found a site that is using the following markup:

```
<span class="some classes" data-id="amf" data-icon="">Title</span>
<span class="some classes" data-id="dmi" data-icon="">Title 2</span>
```

I would like to find out what icon is using and download its content but I do not know how to read its code.

The page is importing jQuery and so I could use the following code:

```
$($.find("[data-id=\"amf\"]")[0]).attr("data-icon").charCodeAt()
```

that returns 58880 <s>(the code of the little square that the browser shows when it does not know the character)</s>.

If I execute:

```
var firstIcon = $($.find("[data-id=\"amf\"]")[0]).attr("data-icon");
$($.find("[data-id=\"dmi\"]")[0]).attr("data-icon", firstIcon);
```

I can see that the first icon is correctly copied in the second span and so it means that I have been able to get the icon from the first span.

UPDATE:
I have verified that if I use a known unicode character, for example

```
<span class="some classes" data-id="amf" data-icon="&#2700">Title</span>
```

the javascript returns the correct code. I am starting to think that the character used in the page is in the unicode map for custom icons.

The page where I found the icons is:

```
https://www.thelifeyoucansave.org/Impact-Calculator
```

UPDATE: As pointed out by @MrLister, the code 58880 is the correct code.

**What is the best way to find the actual icon ?
I need to reuse the same icon in an android app.**

Comment: Haven't I already copied the relevant snippet ? I think that if someone knows the answer, I have already provided the necessary information.

Comment: Here is something you should definitely read. https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode

Comment: I think your hypothesis is probably correct... namely, there being a custom font at work. To help strengthen your argument, it would be worthwhile to see what the CSS `font-family` is for the relevant text. Just using the element inspector in Chrome DevTools should display the `font-family` computed property value. Additionally, see if the name of the `font-family` corresponds with the an imported font (DevTools **Application** tab --> Find the _Fonts_ drop-down, if one exists).

Comment: This is the page where I found the icon: https://www.thelifeyoucansave.org/Impact-Calculator

Comment: @MrLister ah... I see... let me check better